# Multiple Tracking IDs for Single site without named tracker

Tags: google-analytics

In one of my client site, I am seeing multiple tracker IDs without any named tracker. I don't understand why we need multiple tracking IDs for single site?

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-2', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview')
```

I'm new to Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need multiple tracking ids for a single site. This is simply an error. The second tracker instance will immediately overwrite the first one, and hits will be recorded for the second property only.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However I am seeing hits statistics for both properties.

Comment: I do not know what happens on your clients' site, but the configuration in your question will send only one request.